# Expected * before * error (expected specifier-qualifier-list error) in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, pointers

I have the following code:

```
@interface Building : GameObject
{
    CGPoint mapSquarePos;
    CGPoint SquareSize;
    bool isBuilding;
    UIImage *BuildingImage;
    Person *garnisonedPerson;  //Error is here
}
```

i have imported the Person.h file. What could cause this error

Comment: Does Person.h import Building.h?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
@class Person;
@interface Building : GameObject
{
    CGPoint mapSquarePos;
    CGPoint SquareSize;
    bool isBuilding;
    UIImage *BuildingImage;
    Person *garnisonedPerson;  //Error is here
}
```

and importing Person.h in your implementation file

If that doesn't work, it seems BuildingImage could be a class name.

Update for Rickyman20

```
@class Person
```

Tells the compiler that Person is a class.  In general I do not import other header files within my header file.  An example where I do this is when I use cocos2d.

In that case `#import "cocos2d.h` in my header file allows the use of the whole cocos2d library within my header without causing a compiler error

Comment: Variable names are allowed to be identical to class names (it won't cause a compile-time error), although of course it's a terrible idea to actually do that (since it clobbers the class name).

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Now that it worked, What does @class do exactly?

Comment: I updated with a note about @class.  It lets the compiler know that Person is a class and not a typo.  Importing Person.h in your implementation makes all the methods available for your class. (I know  when I have forgotten to do this by the fact that xcode isn't auto-completing my custom methods)

Comment: @class is a forward declaration. It tells the compiler "This token represents a class", but it gives no other information about the class to the compiler. The expectation is that you will `#import` the relevant .h file before you actually try to use the class